# I need to apply free trial period for my auto renewable subscriptions. Can anyone suggest the process for this?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

How to add free trial to auto renewable subscriptions in In App Purchase Swift. I am using SwiftyStoreKit as third party library for payments. How to check whether the subscription is in free trial period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - If you want to add a trial period You have to go to your iTunes account/My Apps/Features/In AppPurchases/Subscription Pricing/Introductory Offers. Set Introductory Offers if you want a free trial to auto Renewable Subscription.

2 - SwiftyStoreKit a great Pod, you just have to fetch the In APP Purchase receipt to check if your subscription is in a trial period or not.

You can use the Demo [here](https://github.com/SwiftGuides/InAPPPurchase-Demo-using-SwiftyStoreKit.git), I made it during implementing the same Auto-Renewable Subscription. and also see the SwiftyStorekit Guide [here](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit#receipt-verification) to see how to fetch Receipt